# Extend controller action timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-core, timeout, cgi

I am trying to generate a report and download it in Excel.
If the returned result is to large the action takes to long and i am greeted with the error message.

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
>
> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

```
public IActionResult GenerateReport(ReportDateRangeViewModel model)
{
    var objections = _reportService.ReportGet(model.StartDate, model.EndDate);

    string sWebRootFolder = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    string sFileName = @"Report.xlsx";
    string URL = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", Request.Scheme, Request.Host, sFileName);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(sWebRootFolder, sFileName));
    if (file.Exists)
    {
       file.Delete();
       file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(sWebRootFolder, sFileName));
    }
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
       //Do some mapping to excel doc
    }
    return Redirect(URL);
}
```

Is there a way to extend the timeout on this controller action?